# Opening new window in MVVM WPF The window is a window, not a user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I really like the solution from GazTheDestroyer to open a new window in MVVM WPF. My problem is that the window I want to show is a window and windows are not allowed in styles.
I have the following lines in my ResourceDictionary:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ConfigViewModel}">
    <vw:WinOptionsSimu />
</DataTemplate>
```

In WinOptionsSimu.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="SimuDMSDMI.View.WinOptionsSimu"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WinOptionsSimu" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/SimuDMSDMI;component/Ressources/DictMainWindow.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

After building the project, the line

is blue underlined and the tooltip shows "Can't put a Window in a style".
How can I solve this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: (Complement) The missing line in my post is : <vw:WinOptionsSimu>

Comment: You should probably link the solution you are talking about.

Comment: Yes probably but I don't know how to proceed